# click event using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello friends i am new on `jQuery` and trying to make a toggle effect. My code is working fine but i also want to to toggle text in it please check following code

**Script**

```
$('.read_more_list').click(function() {
    $(".design_list").slideToggle();
    if ($(this).children('a').html() == 'more') {
        $(this).children('a').html('less');
    }
    if ($(this).children('a').html() == 'less') {
        $(this).children('a').html('more');
    }
})​
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="design_list" style="display: none;">
            <li><a href="#">eCommerce</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Display  Creatives</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Logo Design  Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Microsites</a></li>
          </ul>
<div class="read_more_list"><a href="javascript:void(0);">more</a></div>
```

I want when user click on `more` then it will convert into `less` and when user again click on it then it will change into `more`

Please help me friends thanks in advance... :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/inilip/1/edit)***

```
$('.read_more_list a').click(function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".design_list").slideToggle();
    $(this).text( $(this).text()=='more'?'less':'more' );

});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#">more</a>
```

- You don't need the inline JS void or anything for your `A` button, just use the event handler `event.preventDefault()`.
- To toggle your text you can use a simple Ternary operator `$(this).text()=='more'?'less':'more'`

Just to remind you about Ternary: `[statement] ? [if true] : [if false] ;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`conditional operator ? :`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) to switch between the text along with toggle.

```
$(this).text($(this).text() == "more" ? "less" : "more");
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6CDHQ/2/)**

```
$('.read_more_list').click(function() {
    $(".design_list").slideToggle();
    $('a', this).text($(this).text() == "more" ? "less" : "more");   
})​
```

Comment: Why are you doing `$('a', this)`? `this` is already the anchor :)

Comment: Yes, but the click event is delegated to `.read_more_list` so `this` already IS the anchor.

Comment: If I do not put this in context I refer to div Object and text of div is changed instead of text of anchor, check it here, http://jsfiddle.net/6CDHQ/3/

Comment: My apologies; wasn't looking properly :)

Comment: No worries, I am thankful that you tried to help me for correcting/improving my answer. At the first glance I thought the same as you did.